# Better way to do this subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

Let's say I have this query:

```
<?
     $qi = $db->prepare('SELECT one.id, one.Value, two.Name, three.nfid, temp.Name AS Alias
           FROM one
           INNER JOIN two ON one.fid = two.id
           LEFT OUTER JOIN three ON two.fid = three.fid
           LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id,Name FROM two) AS temp ON three.nfid = temp.id
           WHERE one.rid = ?
           ORDER BY one.id ASC');
      $qi->execute( array( $id ) );
?>
```

Connections between the tables are:

Table **one** contains a number of rows with the fields `one.Value`, `one.rid` and `one.fid`.

`fid` is a connection to table **two** which contains the `two.Name` of the items (`one.fid` = `two.id`).

But sometimes the item is an alias for another item, which is why table **three** exists. It contains the fields `three.fid` and `three.newfid` where `three.newfid` = `two.id` (but for another item with another `two.Name`)

The query is supposed to fetch all rows from **one** with a certain `one.rid` and get `one.Value`, `two.Name` and if there is an `three.fid` for this `one.fid`, get `two.Name` for  `three.newfid` and call it Alias.

Is there a way to improve this query or solve the problem in another way? Perhaps reshape the layout of the database? It is currently quite slow. The example here have been simplified to make it more general.

Thank you.

Comment: Which db engine do you use? Do you have any indexes?

Comment: MySQL and yes, the id, rid, fid and newfid are all indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery in parentheses forces MYSQL to ignore its indexes, which makes it take a long time.  Better to directly join two as temp.  As long as you always put two.[field] and temp.[field], it will tell them apart just fine.

```
  SELECT one.id, one.Value, two.Name, three.nfid, temp.Name AS Alias
  FROM one
  INNER JOIN two ON one.fid = two.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN three ON two.fid = three.fid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN two AS temp ON three.nfid = temp.id
  WHERE one.rid = ?
  ORDER BY one.id ASC
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you for the explanation WHY it was slower.